# java.io.FileNotFoundException: File is not a normal file. alfresco

Tags: java, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to upload the scanned image to alfresco server by using my local structs application . But i am getting above error. I am using Asprise scanner asprise-imaging-core.jar and asprise-imaging-ui.jar trial version to scan the image in server side only.

my sample code for the Action layer below

```
File[] files = ScanManager.getDefaultManager().quickScanUsingUI(new File("C:\\FileScanApplication\\MyApp\\WorkSpace\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\\tm    p0\\work\\Catalina\\localhost\\"), null);

File file = new File("C:\\FileScanApplication\\MyApp\\WorkSpace\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\\tm    p0\\work\\Catalina\\localhost\\jia.JPEG");

String  imeType= URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());

Path source = Paths.get("C:\\FileScanApplication\\MyApp\\WorkSpace\\.metadata\\.plugins\\org.eclipse.wst.server.cor    e\\tmp0\\work\\Catalina\\localhost\\jia.JPEG");
System.out.println(Files.probeContentType(source));
String responseStr="";


responseStr = folderService.uploadDocumen(file, file.getName(),
Files.probeContentType(source), 1);
```

My service layer code here

```
public String uploadDocument(File fileobj, String filename, String filetype, String description, String destination,User user)
{

    Part[] parts = {
        new FilePart("filedata",filename,fileobj,filetype,null),
        new StringPart("filename", filename),
        new StringPart("description", description),
        new StringPart("destination", user.getHomeDirectory())
    };
}
```

Stack trace is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File is not a normal file.
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePartSource.<init>(FilePartSource.java:69)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePartSource.<init>(FilePartSource.java:89)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.multipart.FilePart.<init>(FilePart.java:179)
at com.soldiers.alfresco.Connector.AlfrescoUpload.uploadDocument(AlfrescoUpload.java:76)
at com.soldiers.general.service.documentmgm.FolderServiceImpl.txAddFiletoDB(FolderServiceImpl.java:567)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
at com.soldiers.cfc.aspects.AroundAdvice.invoke(AroundAdvice.java:55)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy33.txAddFiletoDB(Unknown Source)
at com.soldiers.general.actions.documentmgm.FolderAction.execute(FolderAction.java:469)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
at com.soldiers.general.actions.login.LoginInterceptor.intercept(LoginInterceptor.java:477)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: THere is a big space in your path string for `File file = new (...)` and also the `Path source = "..."` line. Is that intended?

Comment: Please also include the stacktrace of the exception you get. This will make debugging this issue easier.

Comment: No file path and file name is going to service layer but in service layer i am getting the above error.

Comment: Check for you PATH in File, To verify try opening in web browser

Comment: Your call is to `uploadDocumen` (without t, four parameters), but you have shown us a method `uploadDocument` (with t, six parameters). Can you show us the real call and the real method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that threw the exception:

```
  public FilePartSource(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
     this.file = file;
     if (file != null) {
         if (!file.isFile()) {
             throw new FileNotFoundException("File is not a normal file.");
         }
         if (!file.canRead()) {
             throw new FileNotFoundException("File is not readable.");
         }
         this.fileName = file.getName();       
     }
 }
```

As you can see, you get that exception with that message if you attempt to construct a multipart that contains something that is NOT a normal file.  I expect that you have supplied the pathname of a directory, or the pathname for something that doesn't exist at all.

(Those spaces in the pathname strings in your example code look mighty suspicious ...)